# Is it possible plot lines using data from a dictionary?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Now I'm plotting using list like this:

```
eje_x1 = (0,6,10)
eje_y1 = (1,1,0)
label1 = 'Label1'
eje_x2 = (8,12,15,19)
eje_y2 = (0,1,1,0)
label2 = 'Label2'

eje_x = (eje_x1, eje_x2)
eje_y = (eje_y1, eje_y2)
labels = (label1, label2)

for x,y,label in zip(eje_x, eje_y, labels):
    plt.plot(x, y, label=label)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

But I want to use a dictionary to clean my code, as the one below.

```
myDict = {
    'Label1': ((0,1),(6,1),(10,0)),
    'Label2': ((8,0),(12,1),(15,1),(19,0))
}
```

Can I plot this `dict` "directly"? I read some posts that one of the axes is the key, but not with this structure.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over the dictionary and rearranging the points in there:

```
for label, points in myDict.items():
    plt.plot(*zip(*points), label=label)

plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

where `zip(*...)` kind of transposes the points so that xs are together and ys are together. The other `*` unpacks these to `plt.plot` to use as first & second argument that happens to be xs and ys,

to get

[image]

---

on `zip(*...)`:

```
>>> points
((8, 0), (12, 1), (15, 1), (19, 0))

>>> list(zip(*points))
[(8, 12, 15, 19), (0, 1, 1, 0)]
```